# What are examples of low- or no-cost laws that favor cyclists? What U.S. state has implemented the most laws?

Tags: road, legal, statistics

There are a lot of parts of bicycle advocacy that cost money. Bikeways. Separated traffic signals. Parking facilities.

I'm not here to talk about any of those. I'm thinking more today about state policies that can be implemented for free or nearly for free -- stuff like the Idaho Stop rule, or declaring an intention to put the Dutch Reach into driver training manuals on the next edit. (Another couple examples: Requiring staggered stop lines where bicycles are present and banning any new on-street perpendicular parking to prevent collisions. Both of these can be phased in during regular maintenance or reference material edits and so cost nearly nothing.)

**Which U.S. state has made the greatest number of these types of "freebies" into state policy?**

Please list the policies implemented to support your answer.

====

EDIT: If it's easier just to list a few such low-cost policies that I haven't listed above, that would also help me in my goal. I'm hoping to write about a few states within a small geographic region, and whether they have implemented "easy" policies for helping cyclists. I can probably research the state implementations on my own, so at this point, just having a list of policies would be the most helpful part of getting answers here.

Comment: I think it would be better to ask about these low-cost laws in a more general sense. Asking for exactly which state has the most (from a purely numerical sense) would require a lot of research or prior knowledge to answer correctly.

Comment: I'm not really sure your question can really be answered.  In my mind there simply are too many vagaries around the intent of policies.  Weather policies are intended directly to benefit cyclists or perhaps a happy bonus etc.  Would also be real keen to know what the reasoning for this question is?

Comment: Thanks, @MaplePanda! I have ammended the question to mention that just having a list of policies would also be a great help to me. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks, @MaplePanda -- this is a good point. See my edit to the question.

Comment: I edited the title for consistency with what you are now asking. Feel free to revert or further edit if it doesn't convey your intent.

Comment: @MaplePanda Isn't "low-cost law" an oxymoron ?  Ballpark figure is a thousand dollars a day per person involved with the legal process, so any nation/state law costs millions by the time it ever gets passed.

Answer (score 1):

One teaching point that has been done locally several times is for a bus/truck company to bring one of their vehicles to a cycling-awareness event, to demonstrate what the drivers can and can't see.

Example

[image]
From https://sharetheroad.org.nz/what-we-do

This is not a US state, there's no policies or laws, and it's not a "freebie" but it is low cost, good advertising, and raises awareness both for drivers and cyclists.